# Непонятный заголовок книги

Tags: склонение

На Валдбрерис продается книга со следующим названием.

Письма Иосиф Римскому
Бродский другу.

Во-первых, смущает то, что имя не в склоненной форме, во-вторых, не понятно, кому адресованы письма: другу Бродскому или Иосифу римскому(император).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иосиф Бродский. Письма римскому другу.

Comment: Спасибо. Запутано очень..

Comment: Светится разная краска: золотая, серебряная)

Comment: Недодизайнеры перекреативили.

Comment: @Буратино,согласен!

Comment: @Буратино Не, нормальный дизайн!  Черный фон, золотые и серебряные буквы. Надо масштаб своего  восприятия менять. Кстати, во всем...  На расстоянии лучше видно. Или в темной комнате попробовать.

Comment: @Sharon Черный мрамор, золотые и серебряные буквы... Фотографии Бродского не хватает и годов жизни - тогда было бы монументальненько, как на кладбище любят.

Comment: Мрачненько как-то все у вас. Жизнерадостнее надо на жизнь смотреть. 10 вечерних образов: как сочетать черный цвет... Черный цвет прекрасно сочетается как с теплыми золотыми оттенками, так и с холодными серебряными. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понятный. Нужно лишь по цветам читать, в любой последовательности:

золотом - имя автора,

белым (или серебряным) - название.

**Письма римскому другу - Иосиф Бродский**

Дизайнерский трюк.